# Is my processor really what it should be?

Tags: processor, vivo

[image]So I was wondering, I just got Iqoo (a Vivo brand) phone and it is supposed to have processor Snapdragon 778g. And now when I go to Settings>About Phone, I see the correct processor name. Ok? But the issue is that when I check my hardware info through any other third party app (and believe me, I have tried multiple apps) then name of the processor that I see is completely different..... Is this normal? For phones to have a different processor?? I need some guidance, so please help. Also check the attached images......
The info on GPU is as follows-
Vendor:
Qualcomm
Renderer:
Adreno (TM) 642L
Maximum Frequency:
550 MHz

Gracias[image]

Comment: Mobile CPU names is complicated as they are really System on a Chip (SoC) and have lots of variations. It may help to list the Graphics Processor Unit (GPU) that is identified.  Should you [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/246777/edit) your post, please consider writing out the info as screenshots are not searchable.

Comment: Where did you buy the phone? If it is a forged phone common system info apps as well as the phone info dialog will not show real phone data. Install Termux app  instead and execute `cat /proc/cpuinfo` (alternatively you can also execute this command via Android Debug Bridge.

Comment: Hardware        : Qualcomm Technologies, Inc SM8350
$

Comment: Same name even after executing commang that u shared. Btw I got the phone from amazon

Comment: Then I don't see a problem. BTW: There are more than 40 devices by Vivo named "Iqoo" so your definition of what your phone is is may be just a bit unprecise or at least you have not mentioned the full name of your phone (which is bad for such a question).

Comment: My bad. This really is my very first question on this forum. I am new to this asking questions business. My phone is Iqoo Z6 Pro. 8gb ram variant+4 GB vram.

Comment: Also one last question, should I be happy? Bcoz I googled and found out that the processor that other app are showing in my phone is actually sdg 888 which is pretty awesome processor

Comment: Or will the 888 chip in my phone (if there) will be a faulty product and thus sold as snap 778?

Comment: Well, this is strange. The SM8350 is the Snapdragon 888, and the Snapdragon 778 is an SM7325, according to [Qualcomm](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/application/smartphones/snapdragon-7-series-mobile-platforms/snapdragon-778g-5g-mobile-platform). This really should not be an 888 being sold as an 778, because they have different cores and the 888 uses much more power. Try installing AIDA64 from the Play Store (it's free with advertising, and usually reliable) and see what it says?

Comment: John bro I am even more confused now. Even In the app u recommended, it still shows Snapdragon 888. But the GPU that my phone has is that of 778g. I am just going to call this a blessing in disguise and stop thinkin bout it.

Comment: https://pin.it/6SlFOxg